# pdf of the F Distribution in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the pdf of the F distribution. I'm using my own parameters and an appropriate range of x values. The plot is supposed to be sm

```
set.seed(123123)
g <- rnorm(10)
h <- rnorm(15, sd = 4)
out <- var.test(g, h, ratio=.25)

out <- data.frame(Type = c(rep("g", length(g)), rep("h", length(h))),
                 Data = c(g, h))

plot(out$Data, out$Type)
```

This plot is just random points that don't visualize a pdf. Any ideas to clean it up?

Comment: Better back up a bit and give us some more context. Why do you think this would visualize a pdf? How are you trying to go about this? Check your code again and make sure it's doing what you think it is, because it doesn't really make sense as is. (And by the way, if all you really want is the pdf, just use `df`.)

Comment: E.g. This will give you the pdf of the F Distribution for `df1=5,df2=5` : `x<-seq(0,5,0.01); plot(x,df(x,df1=5,df2=5), type="l")`

Comment: I think what you plotted are basically points from 2 random distribution `g` and `h`. When you do the `var.test`, which compares variance of 2 distribution it produce the F-statistic `F = var(g)/(var(h)*0.25)` and the p-value `0.1231` is generated from `2*(1-pf(F,df1=9,df2=14,lower.tail=F))`. Hope that helps.